# How to find Masterpage height and width using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, dhtml

How to find Masterpage `offsetheight` and `offsetwidth` using Javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the `MasterPage` height and width just the document's height and width? And by offsetWidth and offsetHeight, do you mean you want the width and height? Offset is usually for left and top.

Use jQuery's [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) methods:

```
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document).height();
```

Comment: i have a masterpage in that i am loading aspx page. in aspx page i have a table

Comment: so i need to dynamically assign a values to that at runtime